# What does |= do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

While trying to fix a bug in another person's code, I found this line:

```
affiliationData.affiliationStatuses |= AffiliationStatuses.affiliatedWithCurrentCrmUser;
```

What does it actually do?

Tried to find it on MDN, but [searching for |= returns zero results](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=%7C%3D).

Comment: It has to be noted that the question this is being marked a duplicate of actually refers to [tag:java] and [tag:android], not [tag:javascript]. Since I searched SO with "[javascript] |=" I didn't find it.

Comment: MDN mainly specifies APIs (eventhough there are MDN resources about this topic). What you're looking for is the ECMAScript (Javascript) language specification. You may want to search for phrases like "ecmascript OR javascript operators", then you'll _definitely_ find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitwise OR assignment

Shorthand operator:

```
x |= y
```

Meaning:

```
x = x | y
```

> [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Answer (score 4):

The `|` is a [Bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) operator.

That statement is equivalent to:

```
affiliationData.affiliationStatuses = affiliationData.affiliationStatuses | AffiliationStatuses.affiliatedWithCurrentCrmUser
```

Answer (score 2):

```
`x |= y`
```

is shorthand of
 `x= x|y` where `|` is a `bitwise OR`

Therefore

```
affiliationData.affiliationStatuses |= AffiliationStatuses.affiliatedWithCurrentCrmUser;
```

is equivalent to:

```
affiliationData.affiliationStatuses = affiliationData.affiliationStatuses | AffiliationStatuses.affiliatedWithCurrentCrmUser;
```